# How can I create this?

Tags: chemfig

[image]

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

    $\chemfig{HO-(-[::+30]*6(-*6(------)-----))=[::-60]O}$

\end{document}
```

It is not 60°, how can you know what angle a substitute has?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please post the `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) When posting code snippets, people should produce a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) providing more information about what they are trying to do.

Comment: MWE: we can copy and compile it - doesn't work with your 1-liner. Why? E.g. we can't know which of these over 40 packages you are using: https://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry . MWE starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document}, provides all needed to show your problem, discards anything else. I.e. it's ready for copy and compile.

Comment: Your document is clearly _not_ `\documentclass \chemfig{HO--[::+30]6(-6(------)-----))=-::-60]O} end{document}`  the above comments were asking you to edit the question so it has a document people can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: A MWE is a document that can be compiled, i.e., for example `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{chemfig} \begin{document} $\chemfig{HO-(-[::+30]*6(-*6(------)-----))=[::-60]O}$ \end{document}` and that allow other users to use the `documentclass` and the packages you are using to be able to anticipate problems that you might have.

Comment: And the question as currently stated is hard to interpret since the oxygen atom makes a 60° angle with the horizontal line. Hence, what exactly is not 60°? If what you meant is the other branch, you should have a `+60` instead of a `+30` at the beginning of your commmand.

Comment: If you know the name of the compound, you can try https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home

Comment: "*how can you know what angle a substitute has?*" — Easy, read the freely available IUPAC guidelines: https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277, namely section *GR-4.1.3 Atoms with four bonds drawn*, which not only provides an exact value, but also thoroughly explains why it should be so. Also, make sure your title is a meaningful self-containing request/question and not an empty clickbait.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I fully understood your question, but I take it that you are unclear about how to rotate the first ring while keeping the angle of the bond that connects the HOO structure to it. You can do this like follows:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

    $\chemfig{HO-([:60]-*6([:90]-*6(------)-----))=[:-60]O}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the other visible atoms added:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

    $\chemfig{HO-([:60]-*6([:90]([:-60]<CH_3)-*6(--=-([:-90]<:H)--)([:150]<:H)-----))=[:-60]O}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's look right. Sorry my Questions was more a chemistry Question then.
How do you know what angle to use, when there a 2 substitute on the same c atom of a ring? U sure that this is the correct angle?

Comment: No, I am not sure, I just thought that it would be multiples of 30 or 60 degrees. You would need to look such things up in some Chemistry book, I guess.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to change the angles, you need to put the second ring and the substituent in the right places. Place the substituents on the second carbon of the ring and the second ring should be on the third carbon.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
    $\chemfig{*6(-(-[:240](=[:300]O)(-[4]HO))(<[:300]CH_3)-(<:[:150]H)*6(--=-(<:[6]H)-)----)}$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case of substituent angles, when there is more than one on the same carbon, what is usually done is to choose angles that do not allow overlap between the substituents or with the ring, and that appear as "natural" as possible, that is, without angles that look too forced.

Over time, after studying many molecular structures, the decision about which angle to use will become much easier.

Comment: That's another way to solve this. But you still need to set the angles for the part where the structure sits at the ring, because otherwise it would point down vertically.

Comment: How did you know what angle to use for the 2 substitutes?

Comment: In the case of substituent angles, when there is more than one on the same carbon, what is usually done is to choose angles that do not allow overlap between the substituents or with the ring, and that appear as "natural" as possible, that is, without angles that look too forced.